# can onSaveInstanceState() of the Activity class be invoked explicitly?

Tags: android

can  onSaveInstanceState()  of the Activity class be invoked explicitly in the code which is written by the programmer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be missing the point????

this.onSaveInstance(saveBundle);

That said, why would you want to do this?  If you have code in there which you want to run outside the callback, why not...

```
private void myMethodToDoStuff(){
   // calculate stuff
   ....
   ....
}

protected void onSaveInstance(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstance(outState);    
    myMethodToDoStuff();
}
```